# How to discover hiding modified humans and their missions?

Tags: science-fiction, aliens, psychology, law, secret-society

Consider an earthlike world where the following happened:

An UFO "crashed" somewhere on Earth some yrs ago.

It sunk into a swamp and was never found (since the swamp was huge and the UFO was small).

Recently, one found a "human" who survived damage that would have been lethal to a normal human.

One smuggled some persons into its social environment who tried to fool it so he tells them his "secrets", but they found nothing, it seems to be inable to talk about private stuff.

One analyzed it, and one found out that its body and its mind were just like normal humans (regarding the capabilities and structure).

Anyway, after several other experiments, that did not answer anything, one tried to kill it, but it survived. (severely but not lethally wounded)

After that, one got interested in what was going on, so one continued with the experiments and one found out that something in its body regenerated the lethal damage each time one tried to kill it.

since one suspected a connction between the UFO and the strange human, one uncovered the ufo.

When one opened it, one found 12 vessels.

Eleven contained nothing (anymore), and the twelfth contained some greyish stuff.

When one analyzed it, one found out that the greyish stuff were [nanorobots](https://www.sciencedaily.com/terms/nanorobotics.htm).

due to some experiments, one found out that the nanorobots were able to form some sort of film and move quite fast as such.

The nanorobots could have gone anywhere on the world (they are fast when on their way as film).

One is powerful enough to interview/analyze millions of humans.

due to further cruel experiments, one found out that these nanobots cause unborn 0th-month "childs" to become nearly immortal "minions" with a certain "mission". (one inflicted small childs with corrupted nanobots (corrupted by radiation, causing them to "contain" corrupted missions), causing them (children) to show some behaviour (doing "mission") that lead to this knowledge.)

since there where 12 vessels, and, usually, if no one splits up the nanorobots out of one vessel they form a single film, one came to the conclusion that there must be 12 "minions" out there (in any country), all at roughly the same age (about one month birth time span).

while the "minions" are not lethally injured, there is no way to detect the nanorobots in the body.

when injured lethally, all nanorobots that are not broken go out of their hidings and regenerate the body as much as necessary for survival.

The "mission" a minion has is more or less its true identity, every "minion" has knowledge and ethical values adapted to its "mission".

Part of every "minions" mission is to play a raw human role, consisting of stereotypical interaction with their family and stereotypical behaviour at work and to avoid unnecessary communication with humans and other "minions" (any communication due to business or stereotypical family life is necessary).

Because a "minion" is a human, it acts "ethical" (like its own ethical values suggest) most of the time.

A "minion" will however never talk (or write etc) about its mission.

A "minion" may lie.

A "minion" does not know that it is a "minion" and immortal.

And here are the questions:

can a suspect prove the agency that he's not a "minion" without dying?

can one/how do one find all 11 missing "minions" using knowledge and resources roughly equal to that agencies knowledge and resources?

can one/how do one find out whats a "minions" "mission" without waiting for it to start doing its "mission" using knowledge and resources roughly equal to that agencies knowledge and resources?

How do one solve the problems above with as little law-breaking (english law) as possible? (law breaking that can't be discovered also counts as law breaking)

Comment: I'm curious how the agency could conclude that "missions" objectively exist under these circumstances.

Comment: they (agency) inflicted small childs with corrupted nanobots (corrupted by radiation), causing them to show some behaviour that lead to this knowledge. added it to question.

Comment: Aha, so this abnormal behavior can be detected and analyzed.

Comment: when they start doing their mission you see what their mission is. but you must find it out before.

Comment: But those small children - did they go into a "mission mode" right away?

Comment: yes, because corrupted nanobots sometimes had corrupted "missions" in their code that had to be done right away, but a mission can also contain a waiting time. (most likely has long waiting time)

Comment: Still don't see how this situation can be told apart from "There are no missions, abnormalities mean that some nanobots are defective."

Comment: I think your question is too "story-based". I would rewrite it to make much shorter and list just the important facts, like "nanobots can't be detected in a body", "children's behavior can be affected in such and such ways" etc.

Comment: Why wouldn't the agency drain the swamp to get to something as valuable as a crashed UFO? There are vast areas of  England such as the Fens that are drained swamps now used as farmland. You could declare something like an accident transporting nuclear material as cover, compulsory purchase the land and get started.

Comment: youre right, but the ufo was small (< 1 m length) (just a little capsule), but anyway, hey, why didn't they drain the swamp earlier? (small inconsistency)

Comment: @ close voters : i revisited the question, now tell me, what is still wrong with it?

Comment: @L.Dutch : i edited the question to make it fit the rules. please tell me, what is still wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

## Basic Information Theory

1. How to prove you're not a minion: Talk about personal stuff, since the only minion previously observed could not do so, that means you are not.
2. How to find missing minions: This is your story, I can't write it for you, but you'll need some sort of test. It would either involve having them disclose personal stuff, or having to do with talking about their mission (minions don't talk about their mission, so if someone does talk about their mission, then they're not a minion). You may need to know something about their mission for this to work. The problem is that it's around 60,000 people based on the 1998 birth rate in the UK. If you were able to narrow it down to a smaller geographical area that'd be useful. I'd also suggest discovering another property of the minions part way through the story to narrow down the list of suspects.
3. How do you find out what their mission is: The answer to this is probably tied to how you know that they have a mission in the first place.
4. Just interview all the possible minions based on what their age is, if you can get them to discuss personal stuff, then they're excluded. Then, investigate all the ones that don't. You're only looking for people born within a 30 day time frame within a certain reasonable distance from the crash site. But it won't be a good story if you can find them all easily, so I'd suggest giving this some sort of twist (they may have to start their missions).

Comment: the nanorobots could have gone anywhere on the world in the 30 days (they are fast when on their way as film). but, your agency is powerful enough to interview/analyze millions of humans. with this in mind you may have the problem that you find many people who dont talk about personal stuff, for example outists. will edit question to clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

Figure out how do nanobots determine "lethal" damage. Then find a way to do it safely as a test. E.g. if nanobots read heart rhythm, you can disrupt it with electrodes.

Look for people born near the crash site. Look for people who survived accidents.

Comment: interesting idea, but what do you do when they check for something you can't simulate safely. (just think of nanobots being in brain cells (neurons), being activated when the brain cells run out of oxygen.)